# How to limit Azure Application Insights to only log custom events in dotnet core project?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I am using an dotnet core api project and have enables it with Azure Application Insight, a loots of data is been sent to Microsoft Azure, how could I limit it so it only sents my custome TrackEvent and disable the rest. Am I able to cofigure it using appsettings.json or programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [ITelemetryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor).

For .net core, sample code like below:

Add a class(assume the class name is MyTelemetryProcessor) to the project:

```
    public class MyTelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
    {
        private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

        public MyTelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next)
        {
            this.Next = next;
        }

        public void Process(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (!(telemetry is EventTelemetry))
            {
                //if it's not EventTelemetry, abandon it
                return;
            }

            this.Next.Process(telemetry);
        }
    }
```

Then, in the Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices method, add the following code:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //your other code

            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<MyTelemetryProcessor>();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If user does not care about anything but EventTelemetry, then the best solution is to prevent other telemetry from being collected in the first place, rather than collecting everything and then filtering out. There are costs to collection which could be avoided by simply disable auto-collection.

Comment: With this solution can you still do your logging with `ILogger` or do you need to need to use the `ITelemetryProcessor` instance itself?

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about logging custom Events, using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights package, and log events using TelemetryClient.TrackEvent API.
I assume you have added application insights package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore and enabled auto-collection of Requests, Dependencies etc. Since you don't want these collected, do not enable auto collection. As Shahzad mentioned, it was probably added for you when you enabled application insights from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

This might happen when you add App Insights using the build in function provide by Visual Studio.
If you just want to log using App Insights and not send all the telemetry data you can do that by simply adding a few things.

In the Program.cs do this

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(String[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
            {
                var instrumentationKey = context.Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey").Value;

                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(instrumentationKey))
                {
                    return;
                }

                // When not in development, remove other loggers like console, debug, event source etc.
                // and only use ApplicationInsights logging
                if (!context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                }

                logging.AddApplicationInsights(instrumentationKey);
            });
```

In your code wherever you want to use it, just inject a logger

```
    private readonly Repository _Repository = null;

    public MyController(Repository repository, ILogger<MyController> logger)
    {
        this._Repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
        this._Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
    }
```

And use it like,

```
_Logger.LogError(exception, errorMessage);
```

For reference [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger)